# How to fill in crevices on a height map

Tags: ios, heightmap, planet, scenekit

I am a very experienced iOS Developer, but I am beginning my very first foray into 3D graphics (specifically with SceneKit).  I'm trying to model a planet, and I have it working with a height map giving mountains and valleys to a simple sphere.

What I'm wondering now is, how might I have a variable sea level?  As I understand it, a height map only affects how the image is rendered, but it doesn't actually change the geometry of the object, correct?  So my first idea, to have a smaller sphere and scale it up or down relative to the planet so that it shows through in the lower-elevation areas, wouldn't work?

If that's the case, how else might I approach this?  I'd love a code sample if it's simple or ready-made, but mostly I'm just looking for a conceptual answer that I can go off and implement.  How might I take a height-mapped planet surface, and have an adjustable sea level that fills in the lower-elevation areas first?  For simplicity, I'm treating sea level as purely altitude-based (i.e. I don't need to factor in dams or obstacles, and maintaining a consistent volume of water isn't important).

Answer (score 1):

You need a 3d noise function (perlin,simplex,..). Call it f(x,y,z). Usualy this function returns a 0..1 float value. You simply decide your sea level float k in 0..1 and :

```
Foreach point of the sphere

If f(x,y,z) < k 

 k is your heigth in that point

Else

 f(x,y,z) is your heigth in that point
```

Comment: This is good info, but I'm looking for how to *execute* the sea level, rather than calculate it.  As in, would it be a second image layer, like a normal map layer on the sphere?  Should it be a second overlapping sphere, resizing in and out?  Is there a way to adjust the height map dynamically to fit sea level?  That sort of thing.  What processes can can be used to create this effect?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to animate the height using u_time in your shader.  Example usage of u_time code in Xcode project download here  - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKit_Slides_WWDC2013/Introduction/Intro.html   (compiles to slide show, use -> key to goto slide 40-something)

Can you help me out?  I've been trying to do a height map with SceneKit's SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry and can't seem to get my (UIImage*)heightMap passed to a sampler2D variable in the shaderModifier.  How are you passing your image?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you explain sounds reasonable. Generate a smaller sphere with the radius set for an appropriate sea level.

Alternativly generate a sphere and alter its scale. This'd be quicker than regenerating a new one.